# How well does GnuCash cope with stock and investment tracking?

Tags: gnucash, microsoft-money

I am used to MS-Money, but need to make a move at some point?

Will GnuCash:

- Automatically update stock prices
- Cope with stock splits
- Cope with stocks in more than one currency

What investment functions I am used to in Ms-money is missing form  GnuCash?

Answer (score 3):

This question has sat for a while, hasn't it?  I converted from Money to GnuCash a few years back, and am very happy with it, though I don't do a lot of investment tracking (just a few funds and a few stocks).  I don't find it as easy to use to enter transactions, a bit more fiddly than Money was, but it does everything I've needed.  It is supposed to be possible to set it up to import share prices, though I haven't even tried that.  The current version of the manual can be downloaded as a PDF file from the website, and here's a direct link to the Investments chapter: http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.4/C/gnucash-guide/chapter_invest.html

Answer (score 1):

> Automatically update stock prices

GNUCash can be told to update prices on startup, but if you're doing it right you don't open it daily. Just for reference / sanity's sake I have a cron job that updates stock / fund prices daily.

> Cope with stock splits

There is a stock-split tool for this.

> Cope with stocks in more than one currency

If you just mean owning international stocks, this isn't an issue. GNUCash allows one currency type per account, but child accounts can have different currencies than their parent. So each fund / stock you own gets it's own account, bought and sold in whatever currency you prefer.